# Перенос пометки "в ожидании"

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, тревоги

Заметил одну проблему, которая хорошо видна на этом скриншоте:
[image: деффект]
Как можете заметить на скриншоте, верхняя пометка "В ожидании" перенесена между строками. Очевидно, проблему можно решить используя неразрывный пробел.

Насколько понимаю, данный деффект требует вмешательства "начальства" (то есть, не входит в полномочия модераторов).

Comment: Вы бы выделили как-нибудь нужный текст на скриншоте, а то я, например, несколько минут искал его.

Comment: @VladD: ок, сделал.

Comment: @VladD Я правильно понимаю, что это лечится корректировкой перевода [в транзифексе](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/64751367?qt=%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)? Каков порядок действия для таких корректировок?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky: Есть несколько человек (например, я), у которых есть права на редактирование. Я могу исправить, вопрос лишь в том, как именно у них принято кодировать неразрывный пробел. Спрошу-ка я Николаса в чате.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky: Поменял в transifex, посмотрим, как это будет выглядеть, когда база обновится.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо! Когда это может произойти? Как часто обновляется база? И как кодируют неразрывный пробел в транзифексе?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky: По идее, Николас время от времени обновляет вручную. Как именно кодируют, мы (Николас и я) пока не знаем, пробуем `&nbsp;`. Если не выйдет, попробуем что-то ещё :)

Comment: @VladD "Всё любопытственнее и любопытственнее..." Напишите, пожалуйста, что получилось.

Comment: @VladD И я правильно понимаю, что для наглядности этому вопросу нужен [meta-tag:статус-воспроизведено] или даже [meta-tag:статус-запланировано]?

Comment: @VladD Можно не полагаться на HTML-ные костыли, а просто ввести символ как есть. :) Он даже в Win-1251 же есть.

Comment: @Discord: Я не уверен, что с ним справится transifex. Может он все пробельные символы нормализует? По крайней мере жёсткие одиночные концы строк он вроде обрабатывает по-особому (но я не уверен).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky: Я до завтрашнего вечера в отпуске :) Думаю, статусы не нужны, всё и так должно быстро решиться.

Comment: @VladD быстрее некуда :)

Comment: @alexolut: Нет ничего более постоянного, чем временное же!

Comment: @VladD Завершено или нет?

Comment: @val: Даже и не знаю. Вы можете воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Нет. Такой вопрос ещё и найти надо.