# Ошибка в метке "в ожидании", видны нечитаемые символы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, тревоги

Ошибка в метке "в ожидании", видны нечитаемые символы:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно связано с исправлением данного вопроса: [Перенос пометки "в ожидании"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3054)