# Некорректный перенос индикатора ожидания проверки тревоги модератором

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, тревоги

Ожидается, что индикатор проверки тревоги модератором, это целостный элемент.
В текущей верстке сайта это не так.

Пример можно наблюдать на картинке ниже.

> [image: Тревога в ожидании]

Чтобы исправить это поведение, достаточно добавить такой стиль:

```
.mod-flag-indicator {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Либо неразрывный пробел в локализацию. Либо `display: inline-block`, что, пожалуй, даже логичнее.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, связано или даже вызвано починкой этого: [Ошибка в метке "в ожидании", видны нечитаемые символы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3068/181472), что в свою очередь было починкой [Перенос пометки "в ожидании"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3054/181472).

Похоже, что неразрывный пробел [можно вставить как `$nbsp$`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40261819?q=nbsp). [Применил этот вариант](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266142?q=pending&qt=%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8), проверим после обновления строк.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, отметьте в том вопросе тоже, пожалуйста, что исправление запланировано

Comment: Обновились строки?

Comment: Ну Alt+0160 же - зачем мудрить?

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно, зачем мудрить, когда можно Alt+Space — но дело не в этом. Явный неразрывный пробел почему-то не работал, уже не помню подробностей.

Comment: @NickVolynkin надо еще раз проверить. Я вчера изменил в транзифексе.

Comment: Не получилось. Но может быть дело еще с Transifex. Они явно поменяли логику сравнения неразрывного и обычного пробелов. Воспринимают их идентично!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это в какой системе Alt+Space? В винде оно открывает контекстное меню окна.

Comment: @Qwertiy конечно на OSX, где раскладки для людей придумываются. И неразрывный пробел есть, и кавычки-елочки, и все буквы с диакритическими знаками — и всё доступно, не надо номера запоминать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и дефаултный текстовый редактор своими кавычками портит код и json...

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Под Windows всё тоже есть: «ёлочки» и длинные тире — если вы программист и [не ленитесь настроить под себя](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько могу видеть, проблема пофиксилась:

> [image: в ожидании]

Как я понял, сейчас есть некоторые проблемы при работе с Transifex в Firefox. В Chrome получилось вставить неразрывный пробел как отдельный символ. Небольшая видео-инструкция по [ссылке](https://www.screencast.com/t/VGxCNSrnN).