# Дубликат, который старее "оригинала"

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

Просматривал свои вопросы на мете и узрел интересную картину:
мой вопрос ([Перенос пометки "в ожидании"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3054/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)), который был задан 14 мая 16 года отмечен как дубликат (отмечен 22 августа 17 года) вопроса, который был задан 7 сентября 16 года ([Некорректный перенос индикатора ожидания проверки тревоги модератором](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3673/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)).

По-моему, данное поведение является несколько странным, поскольку закрыт как дубликат старый вопрос, хотя он существовал на момент открытия нового.

Хотел бы узнать мнение сообщества и модераторов по этому вопросу.

UPD: рассмотрев вопросы и ответы более подробно пришёл к выводу, что эти вопросы на самом деле вообще не являются дубликатами, поскольку было так:

1. Появляется мой вопрос, вносится исправление.
2. Исправление вызывает проблемы, оно откатывается.
3. Задаётся новый вопрос, даётся ответ с описанием хронологии событий.
4. Много позже появляется отметка "дубликат".

В таком случае вопрос: почему эти вопросы отмечены как дубликаты, хотя просто связаны?

Comment: Отмечается дубликатом того, где лучше ответы, независимо от даты.